# Log4j: How to use a custom name for Logger?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I created a Logger with a custom name instead of class name

```
private static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("REQUEST_TRACKER");
LOGGER.info("Some Message");
```

and the pattern is

```
pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS Z} %-5p %-4r [%t] %c{1} %x - %m%n
```

Logger did not print anything to the output.

But When I changed the name is to Class like below

```
private static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ApplicationResource.class);
```

I see output `2018-10-18 13:13:52,805 -0700 INFO  40001 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] com.abc.application.service.ApplicationResource [] - Some Message`

How to configure Logger to use a custom name?

Comment: did you have an appender set up to use the logger with the given name? provide a [mcve] please.

Comment: I am using %c{1}. which worked for a class name but not with a custom name

Answer (score 3):

You must assign the logger to an appender in the Log4J configuration.

If you use XML configuration,
it will look something like this:

```
<logger name="REQUEST_TRACKER">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="appenderNameHere" />
</logger>
```